# Asp.net httpcontext and its working with IIS

Tags: asp.net

can anyone send me a good link to understand "what is Http Context".
when it creates and how it works??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Become familiar with using [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045).

Specifically for the HttpContext, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Have alook at [MSDN - HttpContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)